# Integrate Unity3D project with Xcode as a framework resulting in multiple errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, swift4

Thanks to [this great tutorial on integrating Unity3D project to Xcode](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity), I have a Unity3D project working with in a UIViewController.

On trying to make a framework out of this project or just a blank Unity3D exported Xcode project resulting in so many errors. Can anyone help how to deal with these errors? I am new to Xcode.

```
CompileC /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.o MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -fmodule-name=MyFrameWork -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -miphoneos-version-min=11.4 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wunguarded-availability -fembed-bitcode-marker -index-store-path /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/MyFrameWork-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/MyFrameWork-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/MyFrameWork-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/MyFrameWork-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.dia -c /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp -o /Users/atul109/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyLib-bhrfslgddrzmugfkihkdflsnlynw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameWork.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.o

In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/il2cpp-config.h:7:
/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/icalls/mscorlib/System/String.h:19:5: error: expected expression
public:
^
/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/icalls/mscorlib/System/String.h:17:33: error: variable has incomplete type 'class LIBIL2CPP_CODEGEN_API'
class LIBIL2CPP_CODEGEN_API String
                            ^
/Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/icalls/mscorlib/System/String.h:17:11: note: forward declaration of 'il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::LIBIL2CPP_CODEGEN_API'
class LIBIL2CPP_CODEGEN_API String
      ^
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:70:9: error: no member named 'memcpy' in the global namespace
using ::memcpy;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:71:9: error: no member named 'memmove' in the global namespace; did you mean 'remove'?
using ::memmove;
  ~~^
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/il2cpp-config.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h:108:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:174:6: note: 'remove' declared here
int      remove(const char *);
     ^
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:72:9: error: no member named 'strcpy' in the global namespace
using ::strcpy;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:73:9: error: no member named 'strncpy' in the global namespace
using ::strncpy;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:74:9: error: no member named 'strcat' in the global namespace
using ::strcat;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:75:9: error: no member named 'strncat' in the global namespace
using ::strncat;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:76:9: error: no member named 'memcmp' in the global namespace
using ::memcmp;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:77:9: error: no member named 'strcmp' in the global namespace
using ::strcmp;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:78:9: error: no member named 'strncmp' in the global namespace
using ::strncmp;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:79:9: error: no member named 'strcoll' in the global namespace; did you mean 'strtoll'?
using ::strcoll;
  ~~^
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/il2cpp-config.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:94:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:177:3: note: 'strtoll' declared here
     strtoll(const char *__str, char **__endptr, int __base);
     ^
In file included from /Users/atul109/MyDocuments/Projects/IosProjects/MyLib/MyFrameWork/Unity/Classes/Native/Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues_0Table.cpp:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:80:9: error: no member named 'strxfrm' in the global namespace
using ::strxfrm;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:81:9: error: no member named 'memchr' in the global namespace
using ::memchr;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:82:9: error: no member named 'strchr' in the global namespace
using ::strchr;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:83:9: error: no member named 'strcspn' in the global namespace
using ::strcspn;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:84:9: error: no member named 'strpbrk' in the global namespace
using ::strpbrk;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:85:9: error: no member named 'strrchr' in the global namespace
using ::strrchr;
  ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:86:9: error: no member named 'strspn' in the global namespace
using ::strspn;
  ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Steps done :

1.Created a new project of type Framework in Objective-C

2.Added a folder named Unity and drag and dropped Classes, Libraries and Data from Unity3D exported project (Data with create folder references option checked and others with copy and create groups checked)

3.Added Header search paths and Library search paths.

4.Corrected some missing header errors

5.Added the frameworks which was present in the Unity3D exported project

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]